# How to set "channel" and "hw_mode" of hostapd from userspace (c++ application)

Tags: c++, c, linux, wifi

I have found that hostapd_cli facilitates to configure hostapd from user space or using an external application, but one could set mainly four paramemeters: ssid, authentication, encryption and key.

hostapld_cli command to configure main parameters of access point is:
wps_config "test" OPEN NONE "" (ssid, auth, encr, key)

I would like to ask: 
Is there any way to configure "channel" and "hw_mode" of hostapd from user space.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

A quick grep through the source shows that these are only configurable via the config file.

However setting the channel should really be done using:

```
iwconfig <interface> channel X
```

As the channel setting via hostapd is unreliable with some (most?) drivers.

For hw_mode you could try the iwconfig "modulation" option, e.g.:

```
iwconfig <interface> modu 11g
```

To get a list of modulation options:

```
iwlist <interface> modulation
```